# Mac fullscreen non-one visible application window

Tags: macos, cocoa, fullscreen, x11

I have a cocoa fullscreen application and I also need to show on the same screen another's application window. Is it possible to run from my app a separate process with visible window on fullscreen? May be special tricks/hooks?

Comment: What does this question have to do with XWindows?

Comment: I meant possibility of low-lever tricks to grab window content from some running app and draw it in the fullscreen app manually. May be XWindows experts know such ways

Comment: Any such ways would only work on XWindows apps, though, not on normal Mac apps.

Answer (score 0):

In the fullscreen mode, you can only show a single window of a single application. This system is very strict.

Comment: But may be we have a way to draw another window inside of ours?

Comment: I don't think so. Are you sure there isn't another way to do what you want to do, without having to have two windows on the same fullscreen window?